# libevent как скомпилировать библиотеки под линукс на винде

Tags: c++, linux, libevent

Скаченный libevent-2.1.12-stable вот отсюда https://libevent.org/ необходимо собрать на OS Win 10 и получить библиотеки под линукс с расширением .a и .o
Как это можно сделать и какими средствами.

Comment: Используйте кросс-компилятор.

Comment: 1) apt-cache search libevent; 2) что мешает собирать под линуксом?

Comment: да, я так и сделал)